# Form multiple parent node for each of its descendants

Tags: xslt-1.0

Im quite new to xslt and breaking my head over this issue. Can anyone please help me with this?
Please find the input XML, I need to look for text L1 in id field of L node and search sublocation id and pit ref has text L1 and form new L1 node and arrange sublocation and pit under each L1 nodes.

```
<root>
  <L Id="L1">
    <test>ed</test>
    <SubLocation id="L1S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>1</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SubLocation>
    <SubLocation id="L1S2">
      <check>
        <AId>2</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>2</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SubLocation>
  </L>
  <L Id="L2">
    <test>ed</test>
    <SubLocation id="L2S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>1</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SubLocation>
    <SubLocation id="L2S2">
      <check>
        <AId>2</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>2</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SubLocation>
  </L>
  <cp>
    <current>
      <Amt>20154.00</Amt>
    </current>
    <pi>
      <pit ref="L1S1">
        <value>1232</value>
      </pit>
      <pit ref="L1S2">
        <value>12345</value>
      </pit>
      <pit ref="L1S3">
        <value>12387</value>
      </pit>
      <pit ref="L2S1">
        <value>1232</value>
      </pit>
      <pit ref="L2S2">
        <value>12345</value>
      </pit>
    </pi>
  </cp>
</root>
```

I need the o/p in following format

```
<root>
  <L1>
    <SubLocation id="L1S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>1</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SubLocation>
    <pit ref="L1S1">
      <value>1232</value>
    </pit>
  </L1>
  <L1>
    <SubLocation id="L1S2">
      <check>
        <AId>2</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>2</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SubLocation>
    <pit ref="L1S2">
      <value>12345</value>
    </pit>
  </L1>
  <L2>
    <SubLocation id="L2S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>1</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SubLocation>
    <pit ref="L2S1">
      <value>1232</value>
    </pit>
  </L2>
  <L2>
    <SubLocation id="L2S2">
      <check>
        <AId>2</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>2</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SubLocation>
    <pit ref="L2S2">
      <value>12345</value>
    </pit>
  </L2>
</root>
```

This is my xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="cpbyid" match="pit" use="@ref"/>
  <xsl:key name="slById" match="SubLocation" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="locbyId" match="L" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="L/*[@id]">
    <L>
      <xsl:value-of select="//L/@id"/>
    <pifo>
      <xsl:call-template name="subloc"></xsl:call-template>    
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </pifo>
    </L>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="pit/*[@ref]" name="subloc">
    <inf>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('cpbyid', @id)"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('slById', @id)"/>
    </inf>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am using xslt1.0, and i have issue forming each L1 node, this is my xslt but i dont get required results with this

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when I answered it. Otherwise this would make no sense to anyone reading it and hoping to learn something from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't follow your description that well and I may be missing something. Is there a reason why you cannot do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="pit" match="pit" use="@ref" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="L/SubLocation">
             <xsl:element name="{../@Id}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('pit', @id)"/>
              </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks michael for quick response, im sorry that i was not clear. What i mean is that <L Id="L1"> this "L1" text in id should be compared with <SL id="L1S1"> and  <pit ref="L1S1"> , in this case "L1" text  is in both <SL> and <pit>(id and ref attribute of both sl and pit), so i need < L id="L1"> <SL id="L1S1"></SL><pit ref="L1S1"></pit></L>

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me at this point. Apart from the change of `SubLocation` to `SL` (which you should not have done after I have already answered), how is my result different from the expected output?

Comment: Well, then I suggest you close this question and if you cannot solve for the other scenario by yourself, post a new one.

Comment: @myport I repeat my suggestion above. Comments are not the place to start a new problem.

Comment: I posted new question thanks

Comment: Michael i have posted qstn at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71681231/form-multiple-parent-elements-if-condition-is-met-using-xslt-1, can you please check if you have time.