# Form multiple parent elements if condition is met- using xslt 1

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two scenarios:

- Scenario 1: L node having child node SL
- Scenario 2: L node with no child node SL

I need to form multiple L nodes if text "L1" (`<L Id="L1">`) is found at other nodes like `<SL id="L1S1">` and `<pit ref="L1S1">`.
Id attribute of SL node(i.e `<SL id="L1S1">`) is formed using "L1" in `<L Id="L1">`. Also ref attribute of pit node(i.e `<pit ref="L1S1">`) is formed using "L1" in `<L Id="L1">`,
I need to check whether "L1" is present in either id attribute of SL or ref attribute of pit and form the desired output.

Input xml as below

```
<root>
  <L Id="L1">
    <test>ed</test>
    <SL id="L1S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>1</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SL>
<SL id="L1S2">
      <check>
        <AId>2</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>2</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SL>
  </L>
  <cp>
    <current>
      <Amt>20154.00</Amt>
    </current>
    <pi>
      <pit ref="L1S1">
        <value>123</value>
      </pit>
<pit ref="L1S2">
        <value>1232</value>
      </pit>
    </pi>
  </cp>
</root>
```

Expected output should be:

```xml
<root>
  <L Id="L1">
    <SL id="L1S1">
      <check>
        <AId>1</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>1</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SL>
    <pit ref="L1S1">
      <value>123</value>
    </pit>
  </L>
  <L Id="L1">
    <SL id="L1S2">
      <check>
        <AId>2</AId>
      </check>
      <MD>
        <UnitNumber>2</UnitNumber>
      </MD>
    </SL>
    <pit ref="L1S2">
      <value>1232</value>
    </pit>
  </L>
</root>
```

```
<root>
  <L Id="L1">
    <test>ed</test>    
  </L>
  <cp>
    <current>
      <Amt>20154.00</Amt>
    </current>
    <pi>
      <pit ref="L1S1">
        <value>123</value>
      </pit>
 <pit ref="L1S2">
        <value>1232</value>
      </pit>
    </pi>
  </cp>
</root>
```

Expected output should be:

```xml
<root>
  <L Id="L1">
    <pit ref="L1S1">
      <value>123</value>
    </pit>
  </L>
  <L Id="L1">
    <pit ref="L1S2">
      <value>1232</value>
    </pit>
  </L>
</root>
```

Can anyone help me with a solution which can work for both scenarios?

The above xslt is working for first scenario but fails for second input xml, may be I need to use `contains()` or something like that, I'm not sure of it.

I am using xslt1.0, and I have issue forming each L1 node for second scenario.

```xml
<xsl:key name="pit" match="pit" use="@ref" />
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:for-each select="L/SL">
    <xsl:element name="{../@Id}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('pit', @Id)"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:copy>
```

Comment: Can you please add your XSLT? Also, after fixing the code formatting it doesn't appear that your input shows both scenarios; is it correct? (It at least needs a root element to make it well-formed.)

Comment: Thanks , it took time to format, updated with xslt and scenario

Comment: `select="Location/SubLocation"` but no `Location` nor `SubLocation` element seen in the XML input?

Comment: Just spent some more time to compose a correct question. Now you are using abbreviations in your xml and use the normal xml-names in your xslt. It makes it hard to understand what you want. And in your expected result you use this value L1S2, where does that come from?

Comment: Can anyone please look at it, I hope I am clear this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose in the second scenario there is a relation between the `L/@Id` and the `pit/@ref`. For now I used the assumption that the first two chars of `pit/@ref` should match the `L/@Id`.

If that is correct you could try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
 >
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="pit-SL" match="pit" use="@ref" />
  <xsl:key name="pit-L"  match="pit" use="substring(@ref,1,2)" />
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="L[SL]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SL"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="SL">
    <L>
      <xsl:copy-of select="parent::L/@Id"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of  select="@id"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('pit-SL',@id)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </L>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="L[not(SL)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pit-L',@Id)">
      <xsl:with-param name="L" select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="pit">
    <xsl:param name="L"/>
    <L>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$L/@Id"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </L>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cp"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, exactly what i wanted, but is there a way to extract  L/@Id and find it in pit/@ref?  while forming  <xsl:key name="pit-L"  match="pit" use="substring(@ref,1,2)" />?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. This key finds al pit's based on the the comparison between the substring 1,2 of the pit/@ref and the value L/@Id

Comment: Thanks marking this as answer, sorry i was confused.You made my day:)

Comment: is there any way to form same structure if pit-SL has multiple identical keys?

Comment: To know what you really want, I suggest just start a new question

Comment: I have posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71871953/issue-in-forming-node-structure-when-multiple-identical-keys-found-in-a-nodeset, can you please help me..